# .NET WebAPI and http basic authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, restful-authentication, basic-authentication

I created a `WEBAPI` solution and I am creating the HTML pages to access all the functions of that web service. I am using http basic authentication.

I got these options

1. Save the `username` and `password` in a Javascript vars and send them every time I call any of the `WEBAPI` functions.
2. Send the `username` and `password` the first time, create a token on the server and send it back to the client, then save it as a cookie and use it every time I call any of the WEBAPI functions.
3. Dont use HTTP basic authentication.

What is the best way to handle this?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? We are here for helping you resolving problems but not to write whole bunches of code.

Comment: Thanks, I dont want the code, I want the architectural design answer. Actually I know how to do the 3 options, just wanted to know based on the experience of the ninjas in this community, what is the best approach? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to send the username / password on every call for security reasons.Token based authentication would be the way to go and you can use the built in identity authentication for that.

The best tutorial I have found for that is http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using basic authentication as long as it is done over a secure channel.  If you send the username and password on every call, your api will need to access the database on every call just to authenticate the user.  If you send a token when the user is authenticated, then you remove the need to access the database on subsequent calls.

Using a token also allows you to take advantage of an identity provider such as [Thinktecture's IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) to provide single sign on.  If you have more than a few systems, it will allow users to log in one time and then access any of the applications and it can greatly simplify security.

Comment: does the wep API has the ability to keep that token and validate it each time some request is received?